# Plotting GIS data in R

Tags: r, dictionary, gis

I am new to GIS mapping in R. I am trying to plot the map of Vietnam and 'fill' it with say crime numbers or something. My code is as follows

```
st <- c('HCMC', 'Hanoi','Danang', 'Thanh Hoa', 'An Giang')
lat <- c(10.78, 21.02, 16.06, 19.82, 10.38)
long <- c(106.69, 105.83, 108.24, 105.79, 105.42)
ba <- c(96,99,88,56,7)
bls <- c(0.85, 1.63, 1.09, 0.61, 0.20)
vn <- data.frame(st,lat, long, ba, bls)
```

`st`- state name, `lat`- latitude, `long`- longitude, `ba`, `bls` - other attributes. 
Now, I converted the dataframe into a shapefile for further processing using the code below

```
WGScoor <-  vn
coordinates(WGScoor) = ~long+lat
proj4string(WGScoor)<- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
LLcoor <- spTransform(WGScoor,CRS("+proj=longlat"))
raster::shapefile(LLcoor, "MyShapefile.shp")
```

then I am reading in the shapefile again using readOGR

```
library(rgdal)
viet <- readOGR("MyShapefile.dbf")
```

then I am plotting that using the below code

```
qtm(viet, fill="ba", fill.style="quantile", 
    fill.n=4,
    fill.palette="Greens",
    legend.text.size = 0.5,
    layout.legend.position = c("right", "bottom"))
```

I am getting an output. But it's simply 5 points in box kinda thing. I am not getting it on Vietnam's map.

Comment: Well you need to also plot a basemap if you want a map of Vietnam. So look for a shapefile of Vietnam boundaries or that sort of thing and plot the points on top of that. Alternatively, check out plotting spatial data with packages `sf`, `ggplot2` and `ggspatial`. `ggspatial` provides an interface to download e.g. open street map backgrounds for you plot

Comment: Thank you mikeck. Let me try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When reading shapefiles, you should refer to the file ending in .shp. This is why `readOGR()` did not produce the correct object.

It seems you can read the shapefile using the same function you used to write the shapefile:

```
viet <- raster::shapefile("MyShapefile.shp")
```

Should work ok.

Comment: i ll try and check this as well and get back to you

Comment: i tried this and am still getting the same output. I think i need all lat long points of boundaries of vietnam to get the figure right.